# Unable to open image in Access after inserting it from C#

Tags: c#, image, ms-access-2007, data-retrieval

I am using MS access 2007 for saving an image into it. 
I have given the column name as OLEObject for saving binary data.
I am using the OleDbType.LongVarBinary from my c# app to save images to it. 
After saving the images in access DB, when I am trying to open the image by double clicking on it, I am getting an error like "A problem occurred when MS office access was communicating with OLE server or ActiveX control"

I want to open the image saved in Access 2007 DB by double clicking on it.

Can anyone please give some suggestion on how can I go forward to make this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert an image into an Access OLE field via C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497937/how-to-insert-an-image-into-an-access-ole-field-via-c-sharp)

Comment: I am able to add the images in the OLE filed of accessDB. I just need to open the image directly in the AccessDB itself by double clicking on that particulat OLE field. Anyway thanks for you inputs.